# Moralis-React error when calling the runContractFunction

Tags: moralis

Trying to call the runContractFunction in the Moralis SDK but getting the following errors:
error: {"message":"beneficiary is required in `params`, Function `undefined` is not read only, function_name should not be empty"}

I've entered the beneficiary address in the params already but still getting the error. Your advice and suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the permissions on the parse server folder was wrong. Once the permissions were fixed the runContractFunction was able to access the ABI.